# How can I match common rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

I have a table like this:

```
// friends
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | friend |
+----+---------+--------+
| 1  | 1       | Peter  |
| 2  | 1       | Martin |
| 3  | 2       | Jack   |
| 4  | 1       | Barman |
| 5  | 3       | Peter  |
| 6  | 1       | Jack   |
| 7  | 3       | David  |
| 8  | 2       | David  |
| 9  | 3       | Martin |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Now I have two user_ids. For example `1` and `3`. Now I want to match the rows which have common friends. So this is expected result:

```
| Peter  |
| Martin |
```

Because `Peter` and `Martin` are common for both ids `1` and `3`.

Is doing that possible by pure sql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a self-join of the `friends` table, with the following three conditions being required to match records from both sides of the join:

1. The `user_id` from the first table is `1`
2. The `user_id` from the second table is `3`
3. The friends match (i.e. are shared by both sides)

```
SELECT t1.friend
FROM friends t1
INNER JOIN friends t2
    ON t1.user_id = 1 AND
       t2.user_id = 3 AND
       t1.friend = t2.friend
```

If you have indices setup properly, I would expect this to run faster than an aggregation approach.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT friend
FROM friends
WHERE user_id IN (1, 3) 
GROUP BY friend HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT friend) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
SELECT friend
FROM t
GROUP BY friend
HAVING SUM(user_id =1)>0
AND SUM(user_id =3)>0
```